# How to make a complex query in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**Hi all!**

*New in Django, and confused, help is appreciated! I'm trying to create a table, like:*

| Organization | Appeal Form | Amount of appeals in this form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | In written form | 1 |
| Organization 2 | In oral form | 1 |

Have three models:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class AppealForm(models.Model):
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Appeal(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appeal_form = models.ForeignKey(AppealForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicant_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Objects of **Organization** model:

| organization_name |
| --- |
| Organization 1 |
| Organization 2 |

Objects of **AppealForm** model:

| form_name |
| --- |
| In written form |
| In oral form |

Objects of **Appeal** model:

| organization | appeal_form | applicant_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | In written form | Mary Elizabeth Smith |
| Organization 2 | In oral form | Ada María Guerrero |

*How to make a complex query, to retrieve info from Appeal model? And place to exact fields of the table above?:(*

##########################################################################

**New table in index.html**

| Organization | Total amount of appeals | Amount of written form appeals | Amount of oral form appeals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organization 1 | 10 | 1 | 9 |
| Organization 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: I want to fill the table (the first table above) in the template with just rendered Appeal model, and need to make a query for that, so as I could retrieve and place Appeal model's objects in <td></td> tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a pages app. look where is the template.

`views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Appeal
from django.db.models import Count


def index(request):
    qs = Appeal.objects.values(
        "organization__organization_name", "appeal_form__form_name"
    ).annotate(total=Count("appeal_form__form_name"))
    context = {
        "appeal": qs,
    }
    return render(request, "pages/index.html", context)
```

`index.html`

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Organization</th>
        <th>Appeal Form</th>
        <th>Amount of appeals in this form</th>
    </tr>
{% for item in appeal %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.organization__organization_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.appeal_form__form_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

```sh
pages
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations
├── models.py
├── templates
│   └── pages
│       └── index.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arash, good luck in ur new job! Tried your solution and is working well. Now, it is just my interest: how the query would look like? if the table in index.html will be differently. I have added that different table look below in the question (as New table in index.html).

Comment: Added new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632287/how-to-make-a-query-in-django-that-counts-foreign-key-objects)

Comment: I Thanks for your kind words. I'm glad I could help you. For your new question, I've provided another answer. Hopefully it works for you and you accept my answer. @JSCTPP